# Download file to website using php

Tags: php

I have a file with URL !

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/aa.txt";
```

and I want to download this file and save it to path on my website

this is my website ( online )

```
$path = "server/username/";
```

i want the `$url` file saved to `$path` ,,

i try this

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

when I test the code , it make the file download to my computer not to my website

Answer (score 1):

you can use  `file_put_contents();`

see manual here:http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

a different implementation here:http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-file-download

Comment: i don't want to read what inside the file , i want the file xx.txt to download to my server like www.xx.com/xx.txt

Comment: @AhmedSafadi follow this post:http://serverfault.com/questions/316814/php-serve-a-file-for-download-without-providing-the-direct-link

Comment: Download to another server is a contradiction in terms. Did you mean 'upload'?